# Populate multiple dropdownlists from sql and previous selected value

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropdownbox

I have code in php to query database and populate records in a dropdown list which a user will pick. I also have javascript which populates the second dropdown list based on the selection of the first box.

How do I tie these two together so user selects value "x" from dropdown list, and the php will query the database "WHERE.... = SselectedValue"

Are there any examples online? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: not a big deal, get new list and add the previous one into that

Comment: you can use Ajax with Jquery to query the database.when the user selects the value "x" from the dropdownlist then your Ajax call should be made to the database and you should populate your other dropdownlist with the result returned by the Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an ajax/phpquery call to second dropdown on change method of first dropdown. Eg-

```
$("#firstDdwn").on('change',function(){
   var val=$(this).val();
   //php will query the database "WHERE.... = val"
  //on success of data received from query, populate second dropdown

})
```

Ajax code is supposed to look something like this-

```
$.ajax(
{
      url:"your_controller_URL",
      data: val
      success:function(result){
      //populate 2nd dropdown with result
    },
    error:function(){
      alert("No data received");
     }
});
```

Link for brief info on jquery ajax --- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Is there a tutorial / example you guys know of? I've not done anything with AJAX in the past. Wish this was c# or c++, so much easier!

Comment: Updated my answer with sample jquery ajax and link for tutorial